# How do I write sequentially several tar's to a tape?

Tags: freebsd, backup, tar, tape

I am trying to write several directories to a tape. Each directory with one tar command.

So I have the following sample file/directory structure:

```
user@host1:~/temp/original % find .
.
./foo1
./foo1/foo1.a
./foo1/foo1.b
./foo1/foo1.c
./foo1/foo1.1
./foo2
./foo2/foo2.a
./foo2/foo2.b
./foo2/foo2.c
./foo2/foo2.2
./foo3
./foo3/foo3.a
./foo3/foo3.b
./foo3/foo3.c
./foo3/foo3.3
```

I rewind and erase the tape, which I expect it is like using a blank tape.

```
user@host1:~/temp/original % mt -f /dev/sa0 rewind
user@host1:~/temp/original % mt -f /dev/sa0 erase
user@host1:~/temp/original % mt -f /dev/sa0 rewind
user@host1:~/temp/original % mt -f /dev/sa0 status
Drive: sa0: <SEAGATE DAT    9SP40-000 912L> Serial Number: HN0948V
---------------------------------
Mode      Density              Blocksize      bpi      Compression
Current:  0x24:DDS-2           variable       61000    enabled (DCLZ)
---------------------------------
Current Driver State: at rest.
---------------------------------
Partition:   0      Calc File Number:   0     Calc Record Number: 0
Residual:    0  Reported File Number:   0 Reported Record Number: 0
Flags: BOP
```

Then I want to write three tar files (I think they are called files when stored to tape) with three tar commands. One command for each directory (foo1, foo2 and foo3). So I do:

```
user@host1:~/temp/original % tar cvf /dev/nsa0 foo1
a foo1
a foo1/foo1.a
a foo1/foo1.b
a foo1/foo1.c
a foo1/foo1.1
user@host1:~/temp/original % tar cvf /dev/nsa0 foo2
a foo2
a foo2/foo2.a
a foo2/foo2.b
a foo2/foo2.c
a foo2/foo2.2
user@host1:~/temp/original % tar cvf /dev/nsa0 foo3
a foo3
a foo3/foo3.a
a foo3/foo3.b
a foo3/foo3.c
a foo3/foo3.3
```

As I have been using `/dev/nsa0` I expect to have three tar files stored in the tape.

Now I want to recover the three files from the tape into another directory I do:

```
user@host1:~/temp/original % cd ../backup/
user@host1:~/temp/backup % mt -f /dev/sa0 rewind
user@host1:~/temp/backup % tar xvf /dev/nsa0
x foo1/
x foo1/foo1.a
x foo1/foo1.b
x foo1/foo1.c
x foo1/foo1.1
user@host1:~/temp/backup % tar xvf /dev/nsa0
user@host1:~/temp/backup % tar xvf /dev/nsa0
x foo2/
x foo2/foo2.a
x foo2/foo2.b
x foo2/foo2.c
x foo2/foo2.2
user@host1:~/temp/backup % tar xvf /dev/nsa0
user@host1:~/temp/backup % tar xvf /dev/nsa0
x foo3/
x foo3/foo3.a
x foo3/foo3.b
x foo3/foo3.c
x foo3/foo3.3
user@host1:~/temp/backup % mt -f /dev/nsa0 status
Drive: sa0: <SEAGATE DAT    9SP40-000 912L> Serial Number: HN0948V
---------------------------------
Mode      Density              Blocksize      bpi      Compression
Current:  0x24:DDS-2           variable       61000    enabled (DCLZ)
---------------------------------
Current Driver State: at rest.
---------------------------------
Partition:   0      Calc File Number:   2     Calc Record Number: 1
Residual:    0  Reported File Number:   2 Reported Record Number: 5
Flags: None
```

Why do I have to type twice `tar xvf /dev/nsa0` to extract `foo2` and `foo3`?

If I try to add another directory at the end of the tape I do:

```
user@host1:~/temp/original % mt -f /dev/nsa0 eom
user@host1:~/temp/original % tar cvf /dev/nsa0 foo4
a foo4
a foo4/foo4.a
a foo4/foo4.b
a foo4/foo4.c
a foo4/foo4.4
user@host1:~/temp/original % cd ..
user@host1:~/temp % cd backup/
user@host1:~/temp/backup % mt -f /dev/nsa0 rewind
user@host1:~/temp/backup % mt -f /dev/nsa0 fsf 3
user@host1:~/temp/backup % tar xvf /dev/nsa0
user@host1:~/temp/backup %
```

Why `foo4` is not extracted?

As an additional test I eject the tape, reinsert it and try to extract the four directories, this is what I have to do:

```
user@host1:~/temp/backup % mt -f /dev/nsa0 offline
user@host1:~/temp/backup % tar xvf /dev/nsa0
x foo1/
x foo1/foo1.a
x foo1/foo1.b
x foo1/foo1.c
x foo1/foo1.1
user@host1:~/temp/backup % tar xvf /dev/nsa0
user@host1:~/temp/backup % tar xvf /dev/nsa0
x foo2/
x foo2/foo2.a
x foo2/foo2.b
x foo2/foo2.c
x foo2/foo2.2
user@host1:~/temp/backup % tar xvf /dev/nsa0
user@host1:~/temp/backup % tar xvf /dev/nsa0
x foo3/
x foo3/foo3.a
x foo3/foo3.b
x foo3/foo3.c
x foo3/foo3.3
user@host1:~/temp/backup % tar xvf /dev/nsa0
user@host1:~/temp/backup % tar xvf /dev/nsa0
user@host1:~/temp/backup % tar xvf /dev/nsa0
x foo4/
x foo4/foo4.a
x foo4/foo4.b
x foo4/foo4.c
x foo4/foo4.4
```

Why do I have to repeat the tar commands, twice in the case of `foo2` and  `foo3` and three times in the case of `foo4`?

I am using FreeBSD12.1 and an IBM DDS4 (STD2401LW / Tc4200-236) SCSI Tape Drive.

EDIT>
Following schily's answer, I can get the tar files extracted in order. The only remaining issue would be understanding why `mt eom` to later add `foo4` tar file still requires two `mt fsf` instead of just one.

After reinserting the tape:

```
user@host1:~/temp/backup % tar xvf /dev/nsa0
x foo1/
x foo1/foo1.a
x foo1/foo1.b
x foo1/foo1.c
x foo1/foo1.1
user@host1:~/temp/backup % mt fsf
user@host1:~/temp/backup % tar xvf /dev/nsa0
x foo2/
x foo2/foo2.a
x foo2/foo2.b
x foo2/foo2.c
x foo2/foo2.2
user@host1:~/temp/backup % mt fsf
user@host1:~/temp/backup % tar xvf /dev/nsa0
x foo3/
x foo3/foo3.a
x foo3/foo3.b
x foo3/foo3.c
x foo3/foo3.3
user@host1:~/temp/backup % mt fsf
user@host1:~/temp/backup % tar xvf /dev/nsa0
user@host1:~/temp/backup % tar xvf /dev/nsa0
x foo4/
x foo4/foo4.a
x foo4/foo4.b
x foo4/foo4.c
x foo4/foo4.4
user@host1:~/temp/backup %
```

EDIT>
This is what `mt status` return right at the position that allows to extract `foo4`. The commands are executed right after inserting the tape:

```
user@host1:~/temp/backup % rm -rf *
user@host1:~/temp/backup % mt status
Drive: sa0: <SEAGATE DAT    9SP40-000 912L> Serial Number: HN0948V
---------------------------------
Mode      Density              Blocksize      bpi      Compression
Current:  0x24:DDS-2           variable       61000    enabled (DCLZ)
---------------------------------
Current Driver State: at rest.
---------------------------------
Partition:   0      Calc File Number:   0     Calc Record Number: 0
Residual:    0  Reported File Number:   0 Reported Record Number: 0
Flags: BOP
user@host1:~/temp/backup % echo $TAPE
/dev/nsa0
user@host1:~/temp/backup % mt fsf 4
user@host1:~/temp/backup % mt status
Drive: sa0: <SEAGATE DAT    9SP40-000 912L> Serial Number: HN0948V
---------------------------------
Mode      Density              Blocksize      bpi      Compression
Current:  0x24:DDS-2           variable       61000    enabled (DCLZ)
---------------------------------
Current Driver State: at rest.
---------------------------------
Partition:   0      Calc File Number:   4     Calc Record Number: 0
Residual:    0  Reported File Number:   4 Reported Record Number: 7
Flags: None
user@host1:~/temp/backup % tar xv
x foo4/
x foo4/foo4.a
x foo4/foo4.b
x foo4/foo4.c
x foo4/foo4.4
user@host1:~/temp/backup %
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior is related to the EOF handling of the tape driver.

This handling differs between operating systems and it may help to read the related Solaris man page:

http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man7i/mtio.7i.html

that explains a difference between the Solaris handling and the old BSD behavior.

From this explanation, I would expect the old BSD behavior to cause a read after an EOF situation to skip the file mark and to return the first record from the next file on tape. This seems to be what you expect.

It seems that the observed behavior on BSD is between the documented SVr4 behavior and the old BSD behavior, but I guess that there is a way to make things work on both Solaris and current BSD:

- call tar to read the first tape file
- after that, the tape is positioned at the end of the first tape file, which is just before the file mark...
- call `mt fsf` to skip the file mark
- call tar to read the next file on tape.

From the rest of the discussion, it seems that FreeBSD writes an additional filemark, when `mt rewind` is called after a write operation has been applied.

The command `mt eom` will position the tape after the final double filemark and when another write operation takes place, this happens after the double filemark resultng in an empty tape file before that final write.

A tape with three files looks this way:

```
data1 FILEMARK data2 FILEMARK data3 FILEMARK FILEMARK
```

If you like to append a fourth tape file, you need to call:

```
mt fsf 3
```

to position the tape after the thirf filemark. If you then start writing, this overwrites the fourth filemark and if you then rewind again, you have this tape layout:

```
data1 FILEMARK data2 FILEMARK data3 FILEMARK data4 FILEMARK FILEMARK
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It does work indeed and I understand the reason behind. An additional doubt would be understanding why after `mt eom` and `tar cvf /dev/nsa0 foo4`, it seems like you need to do `mt fsf` twice, like if you would need to skeep two file marks instead of one. Any idea on why that is the case?

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have missed that. Your report looks like there is a double file mark after the third file on tape.Is it possible that your tape driver writes a second file mark before rewinding the tape after the write? On open reel magtapes, it was usual to write two consecutive file marks to mark the end of tape... Could you check what `mt status` reports if you have the tape in the position that would allow you to read the fourth archive?

Comment: I have reedited the question including this new test. Hopefully I position the tape in the right place you wanted to check with `mt status`. I basically inserted it and performed `mt fsf 4` and at that point if I do `tar xv` I get the `foo4`. I executed `mt status` right before extracting the tar file.

Comment: @M.E. This looks as if there is only one file mark and in case that you really need to call `tar x` three times in the other case, this looks like a bug in the tape driver in the kernel.

Comment: Would be the expected behaviour to use `mt fsf 3` instead of `mt fsf 4`? If I am at the beginning of the tape and I want to skip 3 files I would expect to type `mt fsf 3`. Does it look like after a `mt eom` if you do a `tar` it inserts an additional `eof`?

Comment: `tar` does not actively write an EOF mark. but you are right, in order to get to the 4th file, you should call `mt fsf 3`, as this skips 3 filemarks and sould leave you at the 4th file. BTW: `mt eom` is a new opcode originally not in the BSD software, that has been introduced by SunOS in the late 1980s. If you call `mt fsf 3` instead of calling `mt eom`, the next write should overwrite the second of the double filemark.

Comment: Thanks this long thread clarified how tar works.

Comment: I updated the answer with the final conclusions. I hope this is correct.

Answer (score -1):

I have never played with magnetic tapes and tar but to append to a tar archive tar needs to rewrite the last record containing zeroed bytes, which indicates the end of the archive, with the next archive header. So you if your tape is not seekable you may have to rewind every time to let tar read up to that record and then overwrite it.

Also in GNU tar the switch for appending is `-r` instead of `-c`.

If you only concatenate tar files one after the other, GNU tar also has the `-i` switch (on extract) for it to read past the end of the archive, until EOF (in the case of a tape device it *may or may not* be a wise idea - if tar encounters old data at the end of your last archive it may try to extract it, or worse get lucky and find an old archive perfectly aligned...)

I used the `-i` switch to pass multiple tar archives over a pipe, so for me it was not an issue. The same would apply to a normal file which throws EOF at the end.

Comment: Your answer does not seem to be related to the question.

Comment: My answer is agnostic to tape devices which I do not know, however it's important to understand how tar works. A zeroed record at the end of the archive is considered EOF, so to append to a tar archive tar has to go back up and write the next archive header where those zero bytes are. This is consistent with tar extracting the next archive when run again.

Comment: Thomas, did you interpret the question as "extending" a single tar archive as opposed to "sequencing" multiple separate archives?

Comment: "Extending" a tar archive is done by appending to the end of it, so yes to me the OP wanted to extend the archive so that it can be extracted as a whole. Now if instead he extract each separately (by re-running the same extract command once the tape is positioned at the next archive, the end result should be the same. As I said I am tape-illiterate - the only "tape backups" I have ever "used" (so to speak) were on audio cassettes on a TRS-80 and I was still in kindergarden!

Comment: The original post was probably not as clear as this one, which I edited later following schily's comment (he was right, my original post did not include all the required details). So I find normal that some people might have interpreted "extending" instead of "sequencing" (good terms to further clarify the intention). "Files" and "tar" can be misleading specially for those (like me) who haven't dealt with tapes in the past.

Comment: @ThomasGuyot-Sionnest If the question was related to `GNU tar`, it did use the term `gtar` instead of `tar` as the questioneer is not using Linux.  You correctly identified `GNU tar` as an acronym for **GNU tar is not tar**, but in this use case, GNU tar does not deviate from `tar`. The question has been edited, but even the first version of the question was obviously related to file mark handling and not to `updating` a tape archive. BTW: `tar` even knows how to use `mtio` in order to update existing archives on tape but the question was on adding/reading new archives to/from the tape.